# How do I get a loop in python to return to the original while statement.

Tags: python

The loop I created runs smoothly while asking which class to add and when dropping a class. However whenever I try to add a class after dropping one the program just ends instead of going back to the loop to add a class. Where did I go wrong in the program. Below is the code.

```
RegisteredCourses=[]
Registration=raw_input('Enter A to add a course, D to drop a course and E to exit.')
while Registration=='a':
    Course=raw_input('What course do you want to add?')
    RegisteredCourses.append(Course)
    print RegisteredCourses
    Registration=raw_input('Enter A to add a course, D to drop a course and E to exit.')
while Registration=='d':
    DropCourse=raw_input('What course do you want to drop?')
    RegisteredCourses.remove(DropCourse)
    print RegisteredCourses
    Registration=raw_input('Enter A to add a course, D to drop a course and E to exit.')
while Registration=='e':
    print 'bye'
```

Comment: `Registration` doesn't change in the while loops. Just change `while` by `if` and make a global loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't 1 outer loop to ask for user input, there are 3 inner loops. Which is wrong.

once selected, the option remains forever, because the `while` loop, once entered, loops forever (the value of the condition doesn't change *within* the loop)

Instead, make an infinite loop and change your `while` by `if/elif`, and ask the question only once:

```
RegisteredCourses=[]
while True:
    Registration=raw_input('Enter A to add a course, D to drop a course and E to exit.')
    if Registration=='a':
        Course=raw_input('What course do you want to add?')
        RegisteredCourses.append(Course)
        print RegisteredCourses
    elif Registration=='d':
        DropCourse=raw_input('What course do you want to drop?')
        RegisteredCourses.remove(DropCourse)
        print RegisteredCourses
    elif Registration=='e':
        print 'bye'
        break  # exit the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Effectively...`Registration` as a variable doesn't change beyond its first input statement.  This means that you're going to be stuck with whatever value you gave it when you started running this code.

Since it seems like you want menu-like functionality, a simpler way to accomplish this would be to split everything up into methods.

```
def add_course():
    Course=raw_input('What course do you want to add?')
    RegisteredCourses.append(Course)
    print RegisteredCourses

# Other methods for other functions
```

Inside of the main crux of your application, you have a simple `while True` loop instead.

```
while True:
    registration = raw_input('Enter A to add a course, D to drop a course and E to exit.')
    if registration == 'a':
        add_course()
    # Other methods
    if registration == 'e':
        print 'bye'
        break
```

Comment: use `elif` when the conditions are mutually exclusive

Comment: @Barmar:  But the conditions are already mutually exclusive, so further isolating them doesn't seem necessary.  I leave that as an exercise for the reader, though.

Comment: The point is to tell Python that they're exclusive, so it doesn't bother checking for `e` or `d` after it already matched `a`.

Comment: It also makes it clearer to readers of the code that these are exclusive cases.

Comment: @Barmar:  Again...that's really up to the readers.  My code above is more for example and for illustration.